# Phonegap Store Locator get nearest store to current location

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am going to be working on an app which will have a list of locations in a google map and will show all the locations read from an external json file.

Up to there all good but I would like to know if it is possible to have the app detect my current location and alert me if there's a store nearby.

Can this be done? and if it can, would it only work if the application is opened or can I have the app work in the background if the application is closed?

Can anyone give me some light if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a background service. You can `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode` Here's the github page if you need more info on it [cordova-plugin-backgound-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)